# How can I make my answer as a fixed decimal dollar amount in c++?

Tags: c++, currency

Format your dollar amount in fixed-point notation, with two decimal places of precision, and be sure the decimal point is always displayed.

```
cout << "You have made $" << TotalSales <<" dollars from ticket sales!!";
```

Comment: Don't use floating point numbers to represent currency values.

Comment: [std::put_money](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_money)

Comment: @FredLarson how cute, they added a function for homework assignments :)

Comment: @MattMcNabb and you were here at some point so why do you make a nasty comment at me?

Comment: @ThePyroMark My comment is neither nasty, nor directed at you . That's what the ":)" and the "@FredLarson" are for. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [std::put_money](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_money):

```
std::cout.imbue(std::locale("en_US.utf8"));
std::cout << "You have made "
    << std::showbase << std::put_money(TotalSales * 100.0)
    << " from ticket sales!!";
```

This will automatically apply decimal and thousands separators. It will also add the currency symbol if you use the `showbase` manipulator. The formatting of the currency value will depend on the locale you provide.

Answer (score 1):

[`std::setprecision()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/) as well as [`std::fixed`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/fixed/) are the functions you want:

```
std::cout <<std::fixed <<std::setprecision(2) <<"You have made $" <<TotalSales <<" dollars from ticket sales!!";
```